# java json conditional on key name

Tags: java, json

i'm trying to build a sql query from some json data, since the json data i receive always different in the number of fields and contents each time, and all the values are string, so i tried to iterate the json, then convert the values from string to another datatype i.e to_timestamp. but i haven't been able to filter the key name.

i'm very unfamiliar with java. can someone tell me where is my mistake. thanks

```
    for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        if (queryKey.length() > 0) {
            queryKey.append(",");
            queryVal.append(",");
        }

        queryKey.append(key);
        if ((String)key == "t") {
            queryVal.append("TO_TIMESTAMP('" + jsonObject.get(key) + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')");
        } else { //something else }

    }
```

Comment: could you share some json you encountered just to have a better understanding of what you are asking

Comment: @afaq sometimes the json have a key named t and sometimes it doesn't. so i tried to generate the sql based on what is provided on the json. i already have a database with all the possible field names. there is about 50ish field name with various data types with null default,. it is me being lazy to build the complete query. xS.. i tried to filter it with if (key == "t"), but it does not work

Comment: For java you want your check as `"t".equals(key)`

Comment: @Hitobat that worked.. thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed it into :

```
    if ("t".equals(key)) {
        queryVal.append("TO_TIMESTAMP('" + jsonObject.get(key) + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')");
    } else { //something else }
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/362792/hitobat